# How can I access an array inside an object with angular 1.x?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this code:

```
<div class="list" ng-repeat="key in results">
  {{key.locations}}
</div>
```

JSON

```
    [
      {
        "locations": [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20],
        "imgs": ["111.png", "222.png"]
      }
    ]
```

JS

```
.controller('ListCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

  $http.get("js/data.json").success(function(results) {
            $scope.results = results;
          });

})
```

I want to loop trough the array 1,2,3... 
Any help much appreciated!

Comment: another `ng-repeat`

Comment: can I use two at the same time?

Comment: try `key in results[0].locations` and then `{{key}}`

Answer (score 0):

Use another `ng-repeat`, which is nested in the first one:

```
<div class="list" ng-repeat="key in results">
    <div ng-repeat="location in key.locations">
        {{location}}
    </div>
</div>
```

If results always has 1 value, just do this:

```
<div class="list" ng-repeat="location in results[0].locations">
    {{location}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
 
  var test = [];
  $scope.results =  [
      {
        "locations": [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20],
        "imgs": ["111.png", "222.png"]
      }
    ]
    for (var i=0;i<$scope.results[0].locations.length;i++)
    {
       
        test.push($scope.results[0].locations[i]);
    }
   $scope.result = test;
   
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.28/angular.js" data-semver="1.2.28"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div class="list" ng-repeat="location in result">
      {{location}}
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

You can break and create a temp array and then iterate through that array. Please   find the snippet. And let me know your findings